# Need different Reputation method

Tags: discussion, reputation

I have few questions regarding the Reputation thing. According to the site, reputation is the sign of trust.

I have noticed that I highly trust the answers given by high rep users moreso than the low rep users.  Even though I didn't understand fully sometimes what their answer was, but I am 100% sure that whatever he has written is right.

Now consider this case; suppose I have `40K` rep and I usually answer the `c++` or `java` questions.  Now I started answering questions of python or linux for which I am a newbie. Although I have 40k rep up till now, but for python questions I will be like a newbie since I have just started that.
It happened with me that I used the high rep answer and it was wrong. I only relaized it later. Then I saw on the summary page that he is new to this area

Now when I give the answer for python question then its quality will be lower than other person with `5k` rep who is regularly using python.

There is chance the OP uses the answer of `40k` user by just looking at the rep, now that may contain some hidden problems, although the other community members can point that out but there are chances.

I was thinking is there any way we can give an indication along with rep that 40k rep is in c++ or java, but for python he is new.

Comment: You go to the guy's profile and look at the tags. Simple as that.

Comment: So u mean before looking at the answer, i have to check each user summary page if has experience in this field or not

Comment: Don't just look at the reputation of the guy. If you don't understand the answer, you can't check it (and it will probably be wrong).

Answer (score 3):

Reputation does indicate trust.. just perhaps this is not the trust that you are looking for.

What you can learn from a high-rep user is that they are very familiar with how S/O works, that they have answered other questions in a thorough manner (in a way that others have found helpful) and that they can be trusted to vote up or down, comment, answer and generally behave appropriately to the etiquette on Stack overflow.

As mentioned in the comment - you can probably trust their answers higher than a low-rep user... but that doesn't mean that they are infallible in a new subject area. To check out what they earned their rep for - you can go see their tags, and make your own judgement.